# How to reduce the height of ViewController

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller

On a button click, i am opening a viewcontroller as a popup. But it should not occupy the whole screen. It should be 70% of the screen. 
I tried to reduce the height of view controller with properties and CRect size. But it is not reducing the height.

how to reduce height of view controller?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [Help Pages](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and take the SO [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). You should also read about [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as this [Question Checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). To help people answering your question, learn how to create a [Minimum, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

its an easy fix. 
add a UIView inside you ViewController and set the constraints as desired.
set the background color of the ViewController to be transparent.

click here to select the parent view in the ViewController.

[image]

then, click on the color next to background and click custom.

[image]

finally, drag the opacity all the way down to 0 as shown in the image.

[image]